# What does linking/unlinking with Homebrew mean?

Tags: homebrew

What does it mean to link/unlink something with Homebrew?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It symlinks the installed package (located in `/usr/local/Cellar`) to `/usr/local`.

So when you type for example:

```
$ <name-of-binary>
```

in your terminal (ex. `$ rvm`), then the package installed via brew is run.

Answer (score 1):

It creates a symlink from packages installed in Cellar (regular packages installed with homebrew will already be linked).

What this also does is allow the symlinked installation from Cellar to serve as a dependency for other homebrew installations (if it's required). This is explained in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33268663/6447634).

Also with all homebrew commands you get a description of the formulae with the --help option (e.g. `brew link --help`).