# What does "brew link" do?

Tags: homebrew

When I run `brew doctor` I get the common warning:

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
# [...]
```

What does it mean for kegs to be unlinked? And what does `brew link` do exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does linking/unlinking with Homebrew mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175235/what-does-linking-unlinking-with-homebrew-mean)

Answer (score 71):

Homebrew can allow multiple versions of a formula to be installed.  For example, there is formulae called `node` and `node@10` and similar.

```
$ brew info node@10
...
==> Caveats
node@10 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.
```

If I have both `node` and `node@10` installed, where `node` is at v11. I can decide later to active the earlier version with `brew link`:

```
$ brew unlink node

$ brew link node@10

$ cd /urs/local/bin
$ ls -l node
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  admin  34 12 Dec 20:07 node -> ../Cellar/node@10/10.14.1/bin/node
```

Here the symlink `node` is pointing to an earlier version (`keg-only`) installed in `Cellar`.

Comment: `brew link --force --overwrite node@10`

Comment: @themefield  Hi, I had tried this with `gcc@9`with `gcc`already installed but `brew info gcc@9` did not return the => Caveats about keg only that you mentioned above. I was wondering if you knew how to tell the system to use the older gcc v9 in this case?

Comment: use command: `ls -lh /usr/local/opt` to see the list of possible links (parameters options for brew unlink & link)

Answer (score 56):

`brew link` creates symlinks to installations you performed manually in `Cellar`. This allows you to have the flexibility to install things on your own but still have those participate as dependencies in `homebrew` formulas.

See the [FAQ](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#can-i-install-my-own-stuff-to-usrlocal) for more information.

You should follow those instructions and run `brew link` on the entries it lists.

Comment: I was after a more low-level answer: Where do these symlinks reside? What/where is the Cellar? If you clarify with this information I would like to accept this answer.

Comment: The symlinks can be seen with `ls` as normal links. `ls -lh /usr/local/bin/python` => `/usr/local/bin/python -> ../Cellar/python/3.6.4_3/bin/python`. For a complete reference of all the symlinks homebrew manages I am curious too.
Cellar is simply where all the Homebrew packages reside. It is under `/usr/local/Cellar`.