# How to Fix Permissions on Home-brew on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: python, bash, homebrew

When I tried to install python onto homebrew it downloaded it and then an error message popped up at the end that stopped it from completing. When I try to do it again it asks me to do:

```
$ brew link python
```

After entering that the same error message appears:

```
permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/lib
```

I have tried to do:

```
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
```

And I get an error message that reads:

> chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted

Comment: Generally, this is a better fit for [unix.se] or [apple.se], not being directly about *the process of writing software* as is on-topic here.

Comment: Does `/usr/local/` have any ACL parameters, file flags, or extended attributes? Use `ls -le` to check for ACLs, `ls -lO` for flags, and `ls -l@` for xattrs.

Comment: See brew fix here: https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/7732946

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This _is_ the appropriate place for this question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic the guidelines say SO is for questions relating to "software tools commonly used by programmers" and installing Python in a local development environment definitely is a programming task.

Comment: @MartinJoine, but this question isn't specific to Python in any meaningful way. The issue at hand applies to *any* software on UNIX, not the Python interpreter (or otherwise, software-development tools) alone. We don't support someone asking how to repair their CRT because they're trying to use the computer to write programs; similarly, we don't support a generic UNIX question if it's equally applicable to non-programming-related purposes. See the phrase "*unique to software development*" in the same page you linked to.

Answer (score 151):

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/Frameworks
sudo chown $(whoami):admin /usr/local/Frameworks    
brew link python3
```

Comment: @ShivakrishnaChippa the magic above creates: 1) the `/usr/local/Frameworks` directory; 2) changes that directory ownership to the current user and finally 3) `brew link` creates symlinks to installations you performed manually in `Cellar`. More info on `brew link` here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268389/what-does-brew-link-do

Comment: This worked for macos mojave as well. but install of `brew link python3` I choose to do a `brew uninstall python` and then `brew install python`

Comment: worked, but required a `brew reinstall python` as well.

Comment: Worked for me (at least for getting rid of the brew doctor warning) without the need to reinstall python

Answer (score 21):

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/Frameworks

sudo chown $USER /usr/local/Frameworks
```

And then try re-installing python. This worked absolutely fine for me.

Answer (score 15):

Run this, and follow its suggestions:

```
brew doctor
```

In my case, it wanted me to run:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/Frameworks
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/Frameworks
```

Answer (score 10):

I tried and had this same ( I think ) output:

```
Error: An unexpected error occurred during the `brew link` step
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
```

So I created a directory /usr/local/Frameworks as root, and than change the ownership:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/Frameworks && chown $USER:admin /usr/local/Frameworks
```

I tried again `brew install python`:

```
Warning: python 2.7.14 is already installed, it's just not linked.
You can use `brew link python` to link this version.
```

And then `brew link python`:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14... 26 symlinks created
```

Now in directory /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/ I can see links, for example:

```
lrwxr-xr-x 1 niquit admin  62 Dec  8 21:41 /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers -> ../../Cellar/python/2.7.14/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers/
lrwxr-xr-x 1 niquit admin  61 Dec  8 21:41 /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Python -> ../../Cellar/python/2.7.14/Frameworks/Python.framework/Python*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 niquit admin  64 Dec  8 21:41 /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Resources -> ../../Cellar/python/2.7.14/Frameworks/Python.framework/Resources/
```

In your case, I suggest create manually /usr/local/lib:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/lib && chown $USER:admin /usr/local/lib
```

A made a test by `mv /usr/local/lib{,.orig}`, and I got:

```
Error: An unexpected error occurred during the `brew link` step
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/lib
Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/lib
```

Like before I created manually directory `sudo mkdir /usr/local/lib && chown $USER:admin /usr/local/lib`, and successful did `brew link python`:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14... 324 symlinks created
```

Now I can find some links:

```
lrwxr-xr-x 1 niquit admin  54 Dec  8 22:01 python-2.7.pc -> ../../Cellar/python/2.7.14/lib/pkgconfig/python-2.7.pc
lrwxr-xr-x 1 niquit admin  50 Dec  8 22:01 python.pc -> ../../Cellar/python/2.7.14/lib/pkgconfig/python.pc
lrwxr-xr-x 1 niquit admin  51 Dec  8 22:01 python2.pc -> ../../Cellar/python/2.7.14/lib/pkgconfig/python2.pc
```

**I think that Apple after latest update increased security, so its not possible to create now directory in /usr/ without root permission.**

Comment: it's worse than that actually.  you can't modify /usr/local/ without disabling system integrity protection.  it has permissions higher than root.

Comment: @WalrustheCat `/usr/local/` is specifically *not* included in the files protected by SIP. See [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899).

Comment: mine is?  and i've seen results on the internet saying the same thing?

Comment: @WalrustheCat Your `/usr/local` directory lists `restricted` next to it when you run `ls -lO /usr`? That sounds like a *big* problem, and definitely not the way it should be set up. All official Apple docs I've seen (and plenty of unofficial stuff) explicitly *exclude* `/usr/local` from SIP. I wonder how it got that way.

Answer (score 8):

In my case with MacOS 10.14 fresh installation in a new machine:

```
brew doctor
```

And it suggests:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib /usr/local/sbin
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib /usr/local/sbin
```

Answer (score 7):

Command for users on macOS

bash/zsh:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`

fish:

`sudo chown -R (whoami) (brew --prefix)/*`

Answer (score 6):

`/usr/local` can no longer be chown in High Sierra. Instead use

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

Answer (score 4):

Uninstalling and doing a clean install of homebrew will fix the issue.

Comment: I don't quite see how this could work. Homebrew will just try to re-install to `/usr/local/`, and if the permissions are already out of wack, how would that behave differently than the current installation trying to create symlinks? I guess you could force Homebrew to use a different `brew --prefix`.

Comment: How did that work if you have SIP protecting `/usr/local`, as you mentioned in your other comment? How did you even delete the previous installation of Homebrew?

Comment: The brew install script from brew.sh does things that brew doctor does not (yet) know to take care of.

Answer (score 4):

I reinstalled brew and fixed the issue.

to uninstall use the following command.

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

and to install brew again.

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
brew doctor
```

This command, as suggested by Chris above in the comments, solved almost ALL my home-brew issues running on a Mac Mini 2011 5,1 unofficially running MacOS Mojave. Simply enter that and follow all directions that terminal prints

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, by henrikstroem, backticks can be helpful, and as mentioned by bnaecker special attributes might also hinder the process.

You might also try to run the command directly as root to see if better results, by doing `sudo su -` and then `chown -R username /usr/local`

But are you sure that is really what you want?
It might be more interesting to create a group that has an access on it (like `chown -R originaluser:group /usr/local`, set the rights you want, and/or to make your user part of that group.

Comment: I don't think there's a difference between `sudo command` and `sudo su -; command` except for the resulting environment in which `command` runs. And the question is about Homebrew, which definitely requires that the user actually own `/usr/local/` to work correctly.

Comment: I guess on a monouser system it can't be that bad

Comment: guys none of your answers even come close to touching this problem.  i know for a fact you didn't even *try* to *do* what is asked here.

Comment: @WalrustheCat How exactly would we "try" anything? We don't have the problem the OP has, and I'm not about to put in place some obviously difficult-to-disable permissions on one of my most-used directories.

Answer (score 0):

macOS provides a number of ways to control access to files, beyond the traditional permissions for user, group, and other. This includes access control lists (ACLs), file flags, extended attributes (xattrs), and, more recently, Apple's System Integrity Protection.

I'm betting that if you run `ls -lO /usr/`, to list the flags, you'll see `uchg` in front of `/usr/local`, which instructs the system to make the file immutable by any user. (The `u` in `uchg` means that the file owner may modify *this flag*. Neither the owner nor any other user may modify the file itself.)

To solve the problem, you'll first need to remove the flag by running: `chflags nouchg /usr/local`. This should remove the `uchg` flag, which you should verify again with `ls -lO`. If another flag, such as `schg` is set, use `noschg`, or `no<flag>` in general, but you'll need to `sudo` the commands when the flag starts with `s`.

At this point, you may still need to `chown` the directory, with `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local`. You should now own the directory, and Homebrew tools should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

I just did this and it worked ok:

```
sudo touch /usr/local/Frameworks
brew link python
```

Comment: Did I say otherwise? Looks like @Chris' answer is better. Why not post a helpful comment rather than throw stones?