# Homebrew error when installing neovim, how to solve this issue?

Tags: homebrew

I want to install neovim but I'm getting the following error:
 `Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/share`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommended solution:

```shell
$ sudo install -d -o $(whoami) -g admin /usr/local/share
```

A not-so-elegant solution to give permission:

```shell
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Could you recommend me some sources where I can read more about this kind of stuff, meaning I don't really understand some of the flags, just for a reference.

Comment: You could search SO for some similar questions, e.g. this one, it has some great info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47513024/how-to-fix-permissions-on-home-brew-on-macos-high-sierra