# pip3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

I am trying to install dependencies using `pip3` command

current scenario:

```
Dev$ which python
/Users/Dev/anaconda/bin/python

Dev$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3


Dev$ pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

Dev$ pip3 --version
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip3: /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6: bad 
interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I have no idea why my `pip3` command is not working.

I have tried things like this:

```
brew link --overwrite python
```

Answer (score 293, accepted):

You've got a whole slew of different Python installations, plus at least one former Python installation that you deleted.

Situations like this are exactly why running `pip` or `pip3` directly is no longer recommended, in favor of:

```
python3 -m pip install whatever
```

This guarantees that you're absolutely positively running the `pip` that goes with whatever `python3` means, while `pip3` just means you're running  the `pip` that goes with *some* Python 3.x, which may be any of the various ones you've installed.

Or, even better, use virtual environments, so you can rely on the fact that `python` and `pip` are the commands from the currently-active environment, and not even worry about what they mean system-wide.

---

But, if you want to know how you got into this mess and how to fix it:

Your `python3` command is probably from a Homebrew Python (you can check; `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3` and see if it's a symlink to something in `/usr/local/Cellar/python`).

Your `pip3` command is from a Python 3 that doesn't exist. Most likely, you installed another Python 3, which overwrote the `pip3` from the Homebrew Python 3, and then uninstalled it, leaving a broken `pip` behind.

The simplest thing to do is to just `rm /usr/local/bin/pip3`. Then, assuming you want your Homebrew Python to be your default for `python3` and `pip3`, redo the `brew link python` command. If it shows you any warnings or errors, you still have other things to fix. If not, `/usr/local/bin/pip3` should now be the Homebrew 3.6 `pip`, and `which pip3` should pick out `/usr/local/bin/pip3`, and everything is good until the next time you install another Python 3 and overwrite a bunch of stuff.

A better fix would be to pick one way of installing Python—whether Anaconda, Homebrew, python.org installers, or whatever—and use that consistently. Uninstall everything, reinstall the one you actually want, and never touch the others again. (Unfortunately, you will still be stuck with Apple's system Python 2.7, but if you're only using 3.x, that won't matter.)

Comment: I get a segmentation fault when I run `python -m pip install pandas`

Comment: Is there a PEP referencing the "using pip directly is no longer recommended"?

Comment: You can change the line `python3 -m pip ..` to a more detailed python3 version such as `python3.10 -m pip..`

Comment: @user14717 I found a blog post directly from Brett Canon: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: you can also do with `pip3 install xyz`

Comment: I've run `rm /usr/local/bin/pip3` then brew unlink python@x.x && brew link python@x.x. It's worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 31):

You can try to change the python version of pip by doing
`vim /path/to/pip`
Then change the commented line (first line) with the desired version of Python.

Comment: Worked for me, I had the wrong path to Python from XCode and this tip solved my problem. To list areas where you can find pip you can use 'echo $PATH' command.

Comment: This seems a hack as compared to the [answer with most votes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51373253/1705829) with `brew link python`, here is more info to the [brew cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33268663/1705829).

Answer (score 15):

Run the three commands.

```
python -m pip uninstall pip
python -m ensurepip
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 14):

I have the same problem.

For me the path of python in `venv/bin/pip` was wrong.

**1. Open pip:**

> **gedit** path/to/pip

```
#!/home/saeed/project-master/venv/bin/python3.9
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
```

**2. Correct the python path in the first line of `pip` file:**

```
#!/home/saeed/project/venv/bin/python3.9
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
```

Answer (score 6):

I'll made an addition, maybe it can help to someone.

I have `python3.9` installation at this moment, but I get an error message like TS reported:

```
/home/username/.local/bin/pip: bad interpreter: /usr/bin/python3.6: No such file or directory
```

I found that files `pip3.6` and `pip` exists in `~/.local/bin` direcotry with following shebang (note that explicit Python version specified):

`#!/usr/bin/python3.6`

But since I have not 3.6 version on my system, calling

`$ pip`

obviously causes this error. Replacing `3.6` to `3.9` fixes it.

Answer (score -2):

please check your python version on your current environment,ensure it's python3

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo apt install python[2|3]-pip

pip2 install ws4py==0.3.2
```

I've faced the same situation, after above, my program working properly,
Ubuntu 16.04.6 amd64

Answer (score -2):

I have seen same issue while using below command:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

> :bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Able to resolved by using below command:

```
pip3.10 install openpyxl
```

On my Mac machine, python is installed for 3.8 and 3.10 so we need to be specific while installing any module using `pip` command.