# Python/pip bad interpreter : no such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, homebrew

I seem to have lost all the python packages that I had on my Mac.

I entered the command below to upgrade from python3.6 to python3.7:

```
brew upgrade python
```

and now when I enter `ipython3` in the terminal it says:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/ipython3: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

However I was able to use `ipython3` moments before I performed the brew upgrade. Furthermore, I think I have lost all my python packages because when I do an import module in Python3, it says:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named *examplepythonpackage*
```

*Are the python packages that I installed before all lost for good and do I have to re-install them individually now?*

I also cannot run (in the bash terminal) $`ipython3`

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/ipython3: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

For reference:

```
$ which python
    /usr/bin/python
$ which python3
    /usr/local/bin/python3
$ pip --version
    pip 18.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)
$ pip3 --version
    pip 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Comment: You upgraded from python 3.6 -> python 3.7 (from the pip3 output). You need to reinstall ipython3 to get it to work again as it's pointing at the python3.6 interpreter. You need to reinstall all the modules you had under python3.6 in python3.7 in order to get everything working again - none of them carry forward by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51373063/pip3-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1):

The link between `ipython` and which Python interpreter and libraries it uses underneath is established at installation time (as opposed to dynamically every time you run it), so I think your problem will be resolved if you remove and then re-install `ipython`, i.e.:

```
brew rm ipython
brew install ipython
```

If you want to understand this, look at your `ipython` script like this:

```
more $(which ipython)
```

Comment: but ignoring ipython, even if I use `$Python3` (which works), the packages that I had seem to be gone when I do import _package_. Are they gone for good? :(

Comment: Yes, I get that too. If you look at `PYTHONPATH` in your `ipython` script like I show at the end of my answer, it seems to contain `/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/.../python3.7/site-packages` and the `3.7` part means it won't find packages you installed under v3.6. I am not sure what you are supposed to do other than use `pip` to reinstall all the packages you need...

Comment: So just to confirm - the python packages that I installed before are lost for good and I have to reinstall them individually?

Comment: I'm not that good on Python that I want to say that and cause you a load of work that may be unnecessary. Maybe add that into your question and hope a real Python expert wanders by and addresses it before assuming anything about carrying forward packages.

Comment: If you run `brew switch python` it may let you go back to your older version with the packages you had before - as long as you haven't done a `brew cleanup`...

Comment: I have tried your steps but I still can't run `ipython` or `ipython3` in the terminal

Comment: It's very hard to help with *"I can't run python"*. Please click `edit` under your question and say **how** you tried to run `ipython`, **what** happened and also show the output of `type ipython` Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Your packages are not gone but are invisible to your new python. You might try to trick python 3.7 into looking for packages inside the python3.6 directory but then many packages would not work, specifically extension packages since 3.6 and 3.7 are not ABI compatible.

Basically, an upgrade like this requires you to reinstall all packages.