# django-admin startproject command returning bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: django, pip

I can create a project outside of a virtual environment just fine, but when I am using a venv and try to create a django project, I get the following:

```
/Users/justin/Desktop/Programming/Python/Django
 Projects/env/bin/django-admin: "/Users/justin/
Desktop/Programming/Python/Django: bad interpreter: No such
 file or directory
```

I created the venv with `python3 -m venv env`, I then tried to run `pip install django` where the above error also appeared, I then learned I should be using `python3 -m pip install django` ([pip3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51373063/pip3-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory)) and this successfully installed django, but I still cannot start a project. I've ran `pip install django` and `django-admin startproject` from a venv many times without an issue so it seems like I broke something recently. Does anyone know how to fix this/where I can begin looking for the issue? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Save  a copy of your project in another folder and Try again.

        OR


Step First :- RUN - python -m venv env

Step Second :- pip install django

Step Third :- after that install pip

Step Fourth :- ( If your pip version is lower, then it may be issue after 
some time and every time it will show the Warning: for upgrading the pip. 
So if version is lower then USE ) python -m pip install -U pip
```