# Unable to test Mosquitto Server on Mac

Tags: macos, mosquitto

I have installed Mosquitto using brew using

`brew install mosquitto`

And tested whether it is running using

`brew services list`

Output

```
Name       Status  User Plist
mongodb    stopped      
mosquitto  started amit /Users/amit/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mosquitto.plist
postgresql stopped      
tomcat     stopped
```

However, when I try the following from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26716393/3564468) answer I get command not found

```
mosquitto_sub -v -t 'test/topic'
-bash: mosquitto_sub: command not found
```

Do I have to install something else for this to work?

Also, I tried to connect to the broker using a python script, but I get a connection refused message

```
client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect_handler
client.on_message = on_message_handler

client.connect("localhost", 1883, 60)
client.loop_forever()
```

---

**EDIT 1**

I solved the first issue of not being able to use `mosquitto_sub` using `brew link mosquitto`.

But I still get a connection refused.

Comment: Your Python script cannot work *"as is"* because you have not installed nor imported a mosquitto client.

Comment: I have done that. I did not add it to the question cause I thought it was implicit. However, I have figured out the answers. Thanks for taking the time to have a look.

Comment: Well done! Please add your results as an answer and then you can accept your own answer and bag the points and help the community.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some Googling and trying out different things I have figured out the answers to both the questions.

1. The first issue of not being able to start the Publisher and Subscriber clients was solved using `brew link mosquitto`. To check how brew link works you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33268663/3564468) post.
2. Starting the mosquitto broker service as a daemon allowed connections. So simply using `brew services start mosquitto -d` works. I am not sure why this works instead of starting a normal process.