# Git has been installed at `usr/local/Cellar/git` what next?

Tags: git, homebrew

I was updating git using homebrew, and I got git installed at `usr/local/Cellar/git`. What should I do next? Use some homebrew command? Maybe symlink `/usr/local/bin/git`? Maybe just alias it as git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [brew link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268389/what-does-brew-link-do). It will create a symlink if not already present.

```
brew link git
```

Or you can always create a symlink with:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/git /usr/local/bin/git
```