# Multiple versions of Python with Homebrew

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew

The following hack seems to work.  This way I can invoke python3.7, python3.8, and python3.9 individually.  This can be applied to other versions as well.  Thus far this gets all I need.

Is there a better way to do this with brew?

```
# Link python3.7 executables
for ff in pip3.7 pydoc3.7 python3.7
do
    ln -s /usr/local/opt/python\@3.7/bin/$ff /usr/local/bin/
done

# Link python3.8 executables
for ff in pip3.8 pydoc3.8 python3.8
do
    ln -s /usr/local/opt/python\@3.8/bin/$ff /usr/local/bin/
done

# Similarly for any other version of python.
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: No, there's no better way to do this with `brew`.

---

From [reading](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/450303/how-to-make-python-3-11-my-default-python3-with-brew) [around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268389/what-does-brew-link-do) The Stackoverflow network, `brew` always links the default `${brew --prefix}/bin/python3` to the latest stable release of Python (currently 3.11 at the time of writing). This "latest stable release" is determined by `brew` itself: there's no way to override this linking using `brew`.

---

Having said that: you *can* see what `brew` links by default, without linking, with the `--dry-run` mode:

```
brew link --dry-run --verbose python3
brew link -n -v python3 # same command as above, but shorter
```

And then compare it with a non-default version, or potentially use it in your script somehow:

```
brew link -n -v python@3.12
brew link -n -v python@3.9
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

Switching to `pyenv` or `conda`. The python packages (`python@3.9`, `python@3.8`, ...) is designed as dependency for other Homebrew packages. Commonly only the latest python, current `python@3.9`, is used.

My suggestion is never these brew installed python packages for coding. Choose some tools like `pyenv`, `conda`, which takes multiple python management into consideration.